# Remove all elements with specific class except for one

Tags: jquery

I have an select list that has multiple values that are equal. I'd like to remove all duplicates and keep one of them.

```
<select class="pager">
  <option value="#">-- Kies een pagina --</option>
    <option value="some_value" class="active">1</option>
    <option value="some_value" class="pager-current">2</option>
    <option value="some_value" class="pager-current">2</option>
    <option value="some_value" class="pager-current">2</option>
    <option value="some_value" class="pager-current">2</option>
</select>
```

So basically I'd like to do

```
$(select.pager option.pager-current).remove();
```

but keep one `option.pager-current` element.

Is there an option in jQuery to "Select all except one" element?

Comment: which one do you want to keep

Comment: You should accept an answer, Which helped you the most

Comment: I'm going to do that, but I wasn't allowed to accept an answer withing 15 minutes of asking the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you already got your answer, but personally I think [`slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) makes it slightly more readable;

```
 $('.pager .pager-current').
     slice(1).
     remove();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can specify using `.eq()` with `:not` to keep which element and delete the rest in matched dom.use:

```
$('.pager').find('.pager-current:not(:eq(0))').remove();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S8bSs/7/)**